# How to import files that are called the same as the folder that contains them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

When importing files in ECMAScript, we do `import Home from './Home'`, and it's going to import `import Home from './Home/index'`.

I'm in a project where there is no `index` file. Instead, we have a file called the same as the folder that contains it.
For example:

```
src/component/Home/Home.js
src/component/Footer/Footer.js
```

Is there a way to configure NODE_PATH or something, to continue doing `import Home from './Home'` and import `import Home from './Home/Home'`?

Comment: Don't think there is, no.

Comment: I guess the question would be, why are you repeating the name in the first place :P

Comment: @loganfsmyth this is not my project. It's the project of another company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Madara Uchiha said, this is not possible. You could do something clever like this:

In `src/component/index.js`:

```
export { default as Home } from "./Home/Home";
export { default as Footer } from "./Footer/Footer";
```

Elsewhere:

```
import { Home, Footer } from "./component";
```

Hope this helps.